# Spaces in caesar cipher in C

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

This code must encrypt all lowercase letters and show error messages if the input is anything but lowercase. If `Key` is zero, then the input will be reversed.

It works good, but when it comes to spaces, things are going wrong.

What must appear:

```
plain text: notverysecure thiscaeserwas

encrypted text: jkpranuoayqna pdeoywaoanswo
```

What appears:

```
plain text: notverysecure thiscaeserwas

encrypted text: abgirelfrpher guvfpnrfrejnf
```

However if the input is:

```
plain text: notverysecurethiscaeserwas

encrypted text: jkpranuoayqnapdeoywaoanswo
```

My guess is that the space is involved into calculation of `Key`, but my attempts to fix this are doing nothing.

My question is how to make the code to read spaces in the input, but to not involve them into any kind of manipulation

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
//*******************************************************************
// Function to reverse the input string
void rev (const char *const c)
{
if (*c)
{

  rev (c + 1);
  putchar (*c);

 }
}
//*******************************************************************

int main (void)
{
char string[350];
int Key;

printf ("plain text: ");
fgets (string, sizeof (string), stdin);
Key = 256 % (strlen (string) - 1);
//***************************************************************
//ERROR CHECK

if (strlen (string) > 256)
 {
  printf ("[ERR] too many characters\n");
  return -1;
}


for (int counter = 0; string[counter] != '\n'; counter++)
{

  if ( !(islower (string[counter])) && string[counter] != ' ')
{
  printf ("[ERR] invalid characters\n");
  return -2;
}

//**************************************************************

int difference = 0, shift = 0;
for (int counter = 0; string[counter] != '\0'; counter++)
{

  if (string[counter] >= 'a' && string[counter] <= 'z') 
{


  difference = 'z' - string[counter];

  if (Key > difference)
    {
      shift = Key - (difference + 1);
      string[counter] = 'a';
      string[counter] += shift;
    }
  else
    {
      string[counter] += Key;
    }
}
}
printf ("encrypted text: ");

if (Key == 0)
{
      string[strlen(string) - 1] = '\0';
      string[-1] = '\n';
  rev (string);

  return 0;
}
for (int counter = 0; string[counter] != '\0'; counter++)
{
  printf ("%c", string[counter]);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the key is supposed to be `256 % (strlen (string) - 1)`, and not `(strlen (string) - 1) % 256`?

Comment: In any case, your key calculation is definitely including the space when calculating the string length, because why wouldn't it? The space is a regular part of the string

Comment: A space is not lowercase - just saying (re your first paragraph above).

Comment: Just as a side note: check what your program does if you don't enter any text at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for spaces manually in this case while calculating the key

```
int stringLength = 0;

for(int i=0;i<strlen (string);i++){
    if(string[i]!=' '){
        stringLength++;
    }
}

Key = 256 % (stringLength - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, as you have written the code, the `key` is calculated as a function that depends on the original string length (`Key = 256 % (strlen (string) - 1);`)  Two things about this:

- Caesar cipher adds the key to each encrypted char `mod alphabet_size`, so if you encrypt letters, you always get a letter.  This means Key should be in `[0..alphabet_size-1]`  (this is not a requirement, but adding the key to the input char **is**, so be careful here).  In your case `alphabet_size` is 26, so better:

  ```
  Key = some_value_input_from_the_user % alphabet_size;
  ```
- Your key depends on the string length of the original input string, so if you insert spaces, you are changing the string length, and so, the key changes.  It is better to ask first for the key value, or pass it as a parameter. Don't overcomplicate things.